# Managing Large Teams in MS Project

Tags: planning, project-team, resources, ms-project-2016

I am using MS Project 2016. I have been looking at a way to assign tasks to teams rather than to individuals.

This is because I am managing large teams, the compositions of which keep changing, making it difficult to do an individual-resource-wise allocation.

Is there a way to accomplish this, and do a team-wise task allocation rather than an individual-resource-wise one?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I've never actually used MS Project.

Consider, however, exactly what 'resource' means. I have argued before and will argue now that **a resource is not an individual and an individual is not a resource**.

An individual's *time* is a resource.

That being said, why not just create resources for teams' times instead of individuals' times?

That way, you're still assigning tasks to resources. You just need to redefine how you think about those resources.

Comment: Yes, the resources in your schedule will be teams, not individuals. Create the team resources and set the Max Units equal to the number of equivalent full-time heads (people) in the team. For example, if the team has 4 employees working full-time and 2 employees working half-time, the Max Units = 5. This is a standard practice.